# Delphi 7 else if statement error?

Tags: delphi, if-statement

```
Procedure Exchangerates;
var 
  selection: integer;
  answer, GBP, USD, EUR, JPY: string;
begin
  Assignfile(ERfile, 'ER.dat');
  reset(ERfile);
  while not eof(erfile) do
  begin
    read(erfile, er);  
    writeln('Which currency do you want to convert from, euros, pounds, dollars or yen');
    readln(answer);
    if answer = 'GBP' then
    begin
      writeln('GBP');
      writeln('How many pounds to you want to convert to dollars?');
      readln(selection);
      writeln(selection*er.usdtopound:0:2);
      writeln('How many pounds do you want to convert to euros?');
      readln(selection);
      writeln(selection*er.eurotopound:0:2);
      writeln('How many pounds do you want to convert to yen?');
      readln(selection);
      writeln(selection*er.yentopound:0:2) ;
    end;
    else
    if answer = 'EUR' then
      writeln('hi');
  end;
  closefile(erfile);
end;
```

That is the procedure form program which needs to convert between currencies, when  I try running the if statement I get an error, any reason why and how can I fix it? The error is [Error] Currencyconvertor3.dpr(75): ';' not allowed before 'ELSE' , and when I remove the semi colon I get 3 more errors

[Error] Currencyconvertor3.dpr(75): 'END' expected but 'ELSE' found

[Error] Currencyconvertor3.dpr(88): Declaration expected but identifier 'closefile' found

[Error] Currencyconvertor3.dpr(90): '.' expected but ';' found

Comment: *I get an error* is not a useful problem description. You know **exactly** what error you get, and there is no reason for you to fail to include it for us as well.

Comment: SOrry will edit into my post

Comment: The error message you were getting is a clear indication of the problem and how to fix tit. Removing the offending semi-colon `;` resolves the error. The additional errors you mention do not occur with the code you provided.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

```
end;
else if answer = 'EUR' then
```

you need

```
end
else if answer = 'EUR' then
```

The spurious semi-colon terminated the `if` statement.

If you had formatted your code more neatly it would probably have been more obvious what you had done wrong.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunatley I can't upvote you but I appreciate it :)